# Hide Visualforce Page Button in Classic

Tags: lightning, related-list, button, salesforce-classic, page-layout

I have a Button on QuoteLineItem object, which call Visualforce Page. It's related list button and, as far as I know, it can't be an Action - only Buttons supported on this object.
So the issue is that this Button is displayed both in Lightning and Classic, and I need it only in Lightning. Is there some way to remove button from Classic page?

[image: No Action available for QuoteLineItem, only button, which displayed also in Classic]

Answer (score 0):

When you create a custom button, you need to add it to the layouts separately for classic and Lightning.

For Lightning, you need to add button in Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions and for the classic, you need to add in detail section.

> As you want the button to be visible in Lightning only, Just add the
>   button to  Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions and
>   remove the button from the detail section.

Comment: Yes, but that's when you adding it to detail page layout, not for related list. For related list we have multipicklist with all buttons, the only one for Classic & Lightning.